# Programmatically Insert Rows Into Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write a procedure that will check all rows in my table and if `itemID = 'CC100'` then I need to insert a new row into the table.  I have generated this script, but I am getting an error when I try to execute it

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

How should this be altered to become valid t-sql, or what is a more appropriate way to accomplish my desired result?  Sample DDL is below:

```
--Create Holding Table
Declare Table #Items 
(
    itemID varchar(20)
    ,itemName varchar(100)
    ,qty int
    ,storeID int
)
--Insert Some Sample Data
Insert Into #Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) Values
('CZ100', 'Coke Zero', 4, 123), ('CZ100', 'Coke Zero', 3, 201)
,('CZ200', 'Cherry Coke Zero', 4, 311), ('CC100', 'Coca-Cola', 6, 400)
,('CC100', 'Coca-COla', 8, 500)
--Select data that needs to be split into secondary table
Select storeID, Qty Into #NeedExtra from #Items WHERE itemID = 'CC100'
--Declare variables
Declare @storeID int, @Qty int
--Create Cursor
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
--Select statement to insert into variables
  SELECT 
  storeID, qty
  FROM #NeedExtra

  OPEN cursor1
  --Iterate cursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @storeID, @qty
  --Continue as long as cursor is not empty
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --Insert Values
    Insert Into #Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) Values
    Select @storeID, 'CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', @Qty, @storeID FROM #NeedExtra
  --Grab next item from temp table
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @storeID, @qty

END
--Close cursor
CLOSE cursor1
--Deallocate cursor
DEALLOCATE cursor1
--Select statements
Select * FROM #NeedExtra
SELECT * FROM #Items
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your insert query in while loop is not correct.

```
Insert Into #Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) Values
Select @storeID, 'CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', @Qty, @storeID FROM #NeedExtra
```

There isn't a syntax like `Insert into ... values select`, and number of columns inserted is not matched.

And if it's correct the item with value `@storeID, 'CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', @Qty, @storeID` will be duplicate many times equals count of `#NeedExtra`.

The correct query would be

```
Insert Into #Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) Values
('CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', @Qty, @storeID)
```

Second, you should avoid using `CURSOR` and change your `CURSOR` loop by this insert query.

```
 Insert Into @Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) 
 Select 'CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', t.Qty, t.storeID 
 FROM @Items t WHERE t.itemID = 'CC100'
```

Comment: A method with no cursor.  I like this!

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax of `INSERT INTO SELECT` doesn't use `values` keyword. So just remove `Values` keyword from line 33 of your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I altered your code a follows, should work now.

```
--Create Holding Table
    Declare @Items As Table
    (
        itemID varchar(20)
        ,itemName varchar(100)
        ,qty int
        ,storeID int
    )
    --Insert Some Sample Data
    Insert Into @Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) Values
    ('CZ100', 'Coke Zero', 4, 123), ('CZ100', 'Coke Zero', 3, 201)
    ,('CZ200', 'Cherry Coke Zero', 4, 311), ('CC100', 'Coca-Cola', 6, 400)
    ,('CC100', 'Coca-COla', 8, 500)
    --Select data that needs to be split into secondary table
    Select storeID, Qty Into #NeedExtra from @Items WHERE itemID = 'CC100'
    --Declare variables
    Declare @storeID int, @Qty int
    --Create Cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    --Select statement to insert into variables
      SELECT 
      storeID, qty
      FROM #NeedExtra

      OPEN cursor1
      --Iterate cursor
      FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @storeID, @qty
      --Continue as long as cursor is not empty
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
        --Insert Values
        Insert Into @Items (itemID, itemName, qty, storeID) 
        Select 'CC200', 'Coca-Cola Syrup', @Qty, @storeID FROM #NeedExtra
      --Grab next item from temp table
      FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @storeID, @qty

    END
    --Close cursor
    CLOSE cursor1
    --Deallocate cursor
    DEALLOCATE cursor1
    --Select statements
    Select * FROM #NeedExtra
    SELECT * FROM @Items
```

Comment: Ah - rookie mistake!  Thank you.

Comment: if the answer helped you, you can give me an upvote .. :)